# OnTriggerEnter not firing when character enters

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity. I am trying to make a character walk into a spinning gold coin and collect it.

I have a character downloaded from mixamo named 'brute'. in `CoinScript.cs`:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour {
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start(){

    }

    // update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90 * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
        GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), "name: " + other.name);
        if (other.name == "brute") {
            other.GetComponent<PlayerScript> ().points++;
            // Add 1 to points
            Destroy (gameObject); // this destroy things
        }
    }
}
```

`PlayerScript.cs`

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public int points = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        
    }

    private void onGUI(){
        GUI.Label (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 20), "Score: " + points);
    }
}
```

I added `CoinScript` to Coin which is a cylinder object. `coin`:

- Transform
- Clinder
- Mesh Renderer
- Box Collider
- CoinScript
- (I tried to add and remove RigidBody but, `OnTriggerEnter` did not fire)

and for `brute`

- Transform
- Animator
- RigidBody
- Character Controller
- Box Collider
- Capsule Collider
- Player Script
- Move Script

---

I want `OnTriggerEnter` to be triggered when `brute` walk into the `coin`. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the basic conditions for OnTriggerEnter to work correctly:

1. Both objects much have a collider, and one of them should have a rigid body and a collider. the other one may just be a collider.
2. One of colliders should have IsTrigger = true (set from the inspector). if both of them has IsTrigger = true it will not work.
3. If you dont want physics, you may use isKinematic = true on the Rigidbody.

In your case, you also happen to have Multiple colliders on the player's body. make sure they all/ the colliders of interest have isTrigger set to true. The coin, on the other hand can have a collider and a RigidBody with isKinematic = true, and the trigger events should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One of the object must have the "Is trigger"-property checked. If one of your objects (e.g. the coin) is a trigger you can use the OnCollisionEnter function.

Read it: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html